# How do I perform a csharp (or perl )substitution string change the variable for each ocurrence in loop ( regex)?

Tags: c#, regex, replace

I want perform a loop with  global replacement 
and the original subject string change, and  contain previous replacements for each replace

please anyone help me

for example i want to use a chain

and replace like a editor that replace

```
 text match1 text match2
```

replace for

```
  text mathreplace1 "starting after first ocurrence " text match2
```

and starting after first ocurrence and change the string continually

so if I wanted a hypothetical case using the chain replaced the back by a lookbehind
did not have any problem

in text editors each replacement is saved in the chain of operation

IN CONCLUSION

replace and continue the second replace  stored the replace in the subject string of the operation

On until the last replacement

I hope you can understand me

i not have defined code just looking to implement a loop that makes variable the input string in each replacement ; so that i can operate a replacement with regex command but using a variable string with the same command for each replacement

==================================================

I mean that in an operation each time a command is applied regex
the input string is used
if I replace the first occurrence is used the chain input

if I replace the occurrence second again it is used the input string and the position followed the end of match ocurrence

I WISH

it is replaced the first string and then

the result of this operation is used as the new chain
continuing in the position after the match ocurrence
so on

Comment: If you want to, what's stopping you?

Comment: more info? make some effort..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38188920/regex-use-a-command-for-create-replacement-for-each-ocurrence

Comment: This is too broad and too unclear, even at that closed thread.

Comment: hi how i could do a better question?

Comment: I tried to explain  two times any suggestion

Comment: an example would be helpful ^^

Comment: ok I hope you can understand

Comment: @jhonny625: It is a reprint of your former question, and I find it unclear. What makes a question clear: 1) input (sample string, known arguments, how you plan to use them and where), 2) output, 3) example of the code you wrote, 4) description of what is wrong with your code.

Comment: ok thanks but no defined code just looking to implement a loop that makes variable the input string in each replacement ;  so that i  can operate a replacement with regex command but using a variable string with the same command for each replacement

Comment: I do not understand: *that makes variable the input string*, *operate a replacement with regex command*, *variable string with the same command for each replacement*

Comment: It is a bit difficult to explain

Comment: I mean that in an operation each time a command is applied regex the input string is used if I replace the first occurrence is used the chain input

if I replace the occurrence second again it is used the input string and the position followed the end of match ocurrence

I wish it is replaced the first string and then

the result of this operation is used as the new chain continuing in the position after the match ocurrence so on

Comment: i wish implement a feedback replace

Comment: Please do not duplicate comments and the question, remove explanation comments. I have an impression you want to either 1) use a lookbehind, 2) use a loop to replace several patterns (within perhaps an alternation group) with some defined replacements, 3) replace once, then "rewind" the regex index back to 0 and replace once again (can be done in JS, not in C#)

Comment: I feel it is a question about how `Regex.Replace` in .NET works.

Comment: It is exactly what I need if you had any more functional as do thought you would appreciate

Comment: i want rewind and reuse text before match

Comment: Also, bear in mind that the whole text before the match can be inserted during the replacement with `$\`` and what is after the match with `$'`. See http://ideone.com/cCrtQr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my previous answer, I assumed you wanted to be able to change the replacement while looping through the matches. However after rereading I think I understand what was asked.

My interpretation:
Much like in C-preprocessor `#define` you want to unfold and match again.

Example replace `/word/` with `"echo wo"` in string `"wordrd"`:

`"wordrd" -> "echo word" -> "echo echo rd"`

There is a serious problem here, if the replacement contains a match as well, you'd be looking at an infinite word.

Example: replace `/ass/` with `"assassin"`

`"ass" -> "assassin" -> "assassinassin" -> etc.`

To avoid infinite loops/words, this solution checks the index of the last match in the replacement only, and uses the prior match + this offset as a minimum index. Basically:

Example: replace `/ass/` with `"assassin"` in string `"assass"`

`"assass" -> "assassinass" -> "assassinassassin"`

Example replace `/as/` with `"ba"`

`"asss" -> "bass" -> "bbas" -> "bbba"`

Code here: http://rextester.com/PSTV39802 and below

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Text;

/* Basically a context-free replacement, minus the infinite words */
namespace Rextester
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static string replace(string inputText, Regex find, string replacement)
        {
            // to avoid a situation like the following: replace ass with assassin in string ass
            // "ass" -> "assassin" -> "assassinassin" -> etc.
            // it is only allowed to match after the last match in the replacement
            // aka. if we were to replace "ass" with "assassin a" in string "assss" we'd get           
            // "ass" -> "assassin ass" -> "assassin aassassin a"
            int countToSkipInReplacement = 0;
            int minimumIndex = 0;

            Match m;

            // first check if the replacement contains matches as well
            m = find.Match(replacement);
            if (m.Success)
            {
                while (m.Success)
                {
                    countToSkipInReplacement = m.Index + 1;
                    m = m.NextMatch();
                } 
            }

            while(true)
            {
                // uncomment to see all forms in between
                //Console.WriteLine(inputText);

                // find a match
                m = find.Match(inputText);

                // skip until the minimum index is found
                while (m.Success && m.Index < minimumIndex)
                    m = m.NextMatch();

                // if it has no further matches, return current string
                if (!m.Success)
                    return inputText;

                // glue a new inputText together with the contents before, the replacements and whatever comes after
                inputText = inputText.Substring(0, m.Index) + 
                            replacement + 
                            inputText.Substring(m.Index + m.Length, inputText.Length - (m.Index + m.Length));

                // make sure it doesn't go back and replace the text it just inserted again.
                minimumIndex = m.Index + countToSkipInReplacement;
            }
        }

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Regex rx = new Regex("as");

            Console.WriteLine(replace("text before ass between as whatever", rx, "a"));
            Console.WriteLine(replace("sentence without matches", rx, "a"));
            Console.WriteLine(replace("as", rx, "a"));
            Console.WriteLine(replace("as", rx, "as"));
            Console.WriteLine(replace("assss", rx, "ba"));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that this solution is fairly expensive and should be used only when absolutely necessary. (If you have to use a [context-free language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_language)). Please don't use it in performance critical code.

Answer (score 2):

I made a code snippet: http://rextester.com/RLPS43509

I think the code below is the simplest way to do it:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Text;

namespace Rextester
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static string replaceAsWithWhatever(string inputText)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            Regex rx = new Regex("as");

            int prior = 0;
            foreach (Match match in rx.Matches(inputText))
            {
                int i = match.Index;

                // copy the text not matched in between
                sb.Append(inputText.Substring(prior, i - prior));
                // [optional] prepend some text before match 
                sb.Append(" [before replacement] ");
                // replace match with something, possibly permutation of match
                sb.Append(" [replacement of " + match.ToString() + "] ");
                // append text after match
                sb.Append(" [after replacement] ");

                prior = i + match.Length;
            }
            // copy remaining string after all matches to stringbuilder
            sb.Append(inputText.Substring(prior, inputText.Length - prior));
            return sb.ToString();
        }

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // test cases
            Console.WriteLine(replaceAsWithWhatever("text before as between as whatever"));
            Console.WriteLine(replaceAsWithWhatever("sentence without matches"));
            Console.WriteLine(replaceAsWithWhatever("as"));
            Console.WriteLine(replaceAsWithWhatever("as ass ;)"));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do note that you can replace the regex with whatever you want matched, the text before and after and of course manipulate the string matched by modifying the code only slightly.

Comment: If I have not understood your question, please elaborate on what it is you want. If this was the answer you were looking for, please acknowledge this answer.

Comment: thank you very much;
I think that must be the answer;
I check later
very thank

Comment: If it is an answer, the same thing is achieved with 1 call to Regex.Replace. See http://ideone.com/LfNHn8. Why overcomplicate or reinvent the wheel?

Comment: First of all, don't entirely get what the original question was. But with this answer you can manipulate the replacement with every iteration, for instance replace the first occurrence with A1, second with A2 etc.

Comment: I will post a second solution that interprets the question differently but has some drawbacks.